# QGIS Invalid cutline polygon when cutting a raster with mask

Tags: qgis, raster, extract-by-mask

I am working with QGIS 3.10, I should cut some rasters [image: raster] with a vectorial mask [image: mask], but whenever I do it, it gives me error: 'Invalid cutline polygon' and the operation provides a raster with pixel values 1.79769e+308, so invalid.

I tried to verify and fix the geometry of the shape file, I tried to do a buffer, and even tried different algorithms in order to do the cut, but the result doesn't change.

Does someone can tell me how to do it?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of polygon & raster.

Comment: Please provide the cutline as WKT or if it is big, through a link.